# FileZilla Error: Response: 530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I am trying to access an FTP server. The site is still up, so it is the FTP server, although it is a little old. When I enter the username and password, I get this error message

```
Status: Resolving address of sensor.nevada.edu
Status: Connecting to 134.197.38.160:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Command:    USER lapodaca
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

I can't seem to find the problem

Comment: Nothing you can do. Just contact the administrator of the server.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't seem to find the problem.

The error here seems relatively self-explanatory:

```
530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.
```

The remote directory associated with the user account (i.e where the FTP session starts) isn't available. Unfortunately, there is likely nothing you can do to resolve this unless you also control the remote server.

Comment: So if I controlled the remote server, what would I have to do. Basically the remote server is a server set up by a doctoral student that basically had a nervous breakdown and left, so I can possibly get control to the remote server

Comment: Theoretically, if you can get control of the server, then you may be able to adjust the server to allow access to the required directory. That said, `530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible` is a generic error, so you may need to do some troubleshooting. The first things that you may want to check are 1) that the specified user account exists 2) that the account isn't locked or disabled and 3) the account has the correct permissions to access the relevant home directory (or what have you).

Comment: If you control the server you need to update your question to reflect that. Your question right now implies you're connecting to a server someone else controls.